# How to create a shadowDOM with bootstrap dropdown menu in JS

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, shadow-dom

I am creating a chrome extension where i need to add the split-button provided by the bootstrap as a shadowDOM. but i couldn't find any clear documentation for it.Could someone tell me how to create a shadowDOM which would inject the bootstrap css, js and popper js file.

I have tried like below but the button was not visible.

```
const shadowHost = document.getElementById('my-shadow-host');
const shadowRoot = shadowHost.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });

  // Bootstrap button and dropdown menu HTML
const bootstrapButtonAndDropdown = `
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Bootstrap Button</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
      <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
`;

  // Append Bootstrap components to the shadow root
  shadowRoot.innerHTML = bootstrapButtonAndDropdown;

  // Add an event listener to the button inside the Shadow DOM
  const buttonInsideShadowDom = shadowRoot.querySelector('.btn-primary');
  buttonInsideShadowDom.addEventListener('click', () => {
    alert('Button inside Shadow DOM clicked!');
  });

class SplitButton extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.render();
  }

  render() {
    this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
    this.shadowRoot.innerHTML += template;
  }
}

window.customElements.define("split-button", SplitButton);
```

Calling the splitbutton

```
const button = document.createElement('split-button');
```

But the button returns null.

Comment: You can help us answering your question, by adding a [minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I refactored your code; should be self explanatory
Note, you are not going to add multiple listners, so no need for `addEventListener`

```html
<split-button></split-button>
<script>
  customElements.define("split-button", class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super().attachShadow({
        mode: "open"
      }).innerHTML = `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Bootstrap Button</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
      <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
    </div>
  </div>`;
      this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.btn-primary').onclick = () => alert('Button inside Shadow DOM clicked!');
    }
  });

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for it but in case if we need to use the dropdown menu how we can include the popper js and the bootstrap.min.js script tags in it. Or do we need to do it in a different way

Comment: **provided** the libraries support shadowDOM (and most don't, as they do things like ``document.getElementById()``), you add them as above ``<link>`` **inside** the shadowDOM. Contact the vendors of those libraries, if something is wrong with your car, you don't go the pub to ask a question, you go to the vendor.